# SQL database query display extra dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am making a database with postgresql 9.1
Given tables:

```
CREATE TABLE rooms(
    room_number int,
    property_id int,
    type character varying,
    PRIMARY KEY (room_number, property_id)
);
Insert into rooms values (1,1,double),(2,1,double),(3,1,triple)

CREATE TABLE reservations(
    reservation_ID int,
    property_id int,
    arrival date,
    departure date,
    room_num int,
    PRIMARY KEY(reservation_ID,property_id)
    FOREIGN KEY (room_number, property_id)
);

INSERT INTO orders VALUES (1,1,2013-9-27,2013-9-30,1), 
                          (2,1,2013-9-27,2013-9-28,2),
                          (3,1,2013-9-29,2013-9-30,3);
```

I want to give 2 dates and check availability in between. So at the 1st column should apear:

1. all the dates between the given and
2. additional one column for every type of the room displaying the availability.

So my result, given 2013-9-27 & 2013-9-30 as input, must be sth like this:

[image]

Comment: What is the part causing you difficulty?

Comment: I can display an attribute that there is in the table. But the dates that must be displayed is delimited by arrival and departure attributes. So I want somehow to display dates that there are not exist as attributes but there are bounded.

Comment: But also, how can I display they types of the room to additional columns, without knowing how many types exists in advance?

Comment: You have to do it with sql and it is a tough query.  If it were my problem, I'd break it down into baby steps.  First I'd get my input parameters to work with arrival dates only.  Then I'd get them to work with departure dates only.  From there, combining the two should be easier than if you tried everything at once.

Comment: Check out the `crosstab()` function in the `tablefunc` module: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/tablefunc.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution would be use both generate_series() and crosstab() to create a dynamic table.  Moreover you can use a left join from a CTE to your data tables so you get better information.  Something like:

```
 WITH daterange as (
      SELECT s::date as day FROM generate_series(?, ?, '1 day')
 )
 SELECT dr.day, sum(case when r.type = 'double' then r.qty else 0) as room_double,
        sum(case when r.type = 'triple' then r.qty else 0) as room_triple....
 );
```

But note that crosstab would make the second query a little easier.